# No records from JDBC Source Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I load the below json file with 
./confluent load CRM_TEST -d /kafka/CRM_TEST.json 
then there is a 20 second or so lag and then no message is prompted, I assume it's successfully added. I check the connect log I don't see any entries the Source is not created and the topic is not created. What could be going on here

```
{ 
"name":"CRMMASTP_SOURCE", 
"config":{ 
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector", 
"tasks.max":"1", 
"topic.prefix":"CRMMASTP_TOPIC", 
"connection.url":"jdbc:as400://<IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT>/<DATABASE>", 
"connection.user":"unifi_srvc", 
"connection.password":"weblogin", 
"key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter", 
"key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081", 
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter", 
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081", 
"mode": "bulk", 
"query": "SELECT * FROM DATABASE.TABLE limit 10", 
"poll.interval.ms": "60000", 
"batch.max.rows": "10000", 
"table.types": "TABLE", 
"plugin.path":"/confluent-4.1.0/share/java" 
} 
}
```

Comment: Don't see any logs, or don't see any errors? Can you please add the connect server logs after posting the configuration? Did you check http://localhost:8083/connectors/CRMMASTP_SOURCE/status?

Comment: `confluent log connect` will show the complete Connect log. In here you should see the connector loaded and then either an error, or successful processing.

Comment: This command shows all connectors & their state. What's its output when you run it?  `curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors"| jq '.[]'| xargs -I{connector_name} curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors/"{connector_name}"/status"| jq -c -M '[.name,.connector.state,.tasks[].state]|join(":|:")'| column -s : -t| sed 's/\"//g'| sort`